# Sass::SyntaxError in Visitors#new

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I am new to Ruby and eager to learn! I am now following the tutorial from the capstone Rails tutorial book 1, but having a small problem. I hope you guys can and will help me.

I have made a application with Zurb Foundation, and now the tutorial tells me to test it, but I get an error. I can't find the solution on Google..
I am using Ruby 2.1.5 via Nitrous.io.
  I will add all the information I see, so sorry if this is not the way, but just let me know so I can improve this in the future! Here we go:

When I start the server and wants to preview,
I get this error:

```
**Sass::SyntaxError in Visitors#new**  


*Showing /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #7 raised:  
Invalid CSS after "...ules: $modules ": expected "}", was "!global;"  
  (in /home/action/workspace/learn-rails/app/assets/stylesheets/framework_and_overrides.css.scss:13)*    

4 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
5 <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Learn Rails" %></title>
6 <meta name="description" content="<%= content_for?(:description) ? yield(:description) : "Learn Rails" %>">
7 <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
8  <%# Modernizr is required for Zurb Foundation %>
9 <%= javascript_include_tag 'vendor/modernizr' %>
10 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Application trace:

```
app/assets/stylesheets/framework_and_overrides.css.scss:2
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:7:in     '_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___1613058967742566382_40390520'
```

EDIT 5-1-014. This is in Framework_and_overrides.css.scss

```
// import the CSS framework
@import "foundation";

// override for the 'Home' navigation link
.top-bar .name {
  font-size: rem-calc(13);
  line-height: 45px; }
.top-bar .name a {
  font-weight: normal;
  color: white;
  padding: 0 15px; }

// THESE ARE EXAMPLES YOU CAN MODIFY
// create mixins using Foundation classes
@mixin twelve-columns {
  @extend .small-12;
  @extend .columns;
  }
@mixin six-columns-centered {
  @extend .small-6;
  @extend .columns;
  @extend .text-center;
  }
// create your own classes
// to make views framework-neutral
.column {
  @include six-columns-centered;
  }
.form {
  @include grid-column(6);
  }
.form-centered {
  @include six-columns-centered;
  }
.submit {
  @extend .button;
  @extend .radius;
  }
// apply styles to HTML elements
// to make views framework-neutral
main {
  @include twelve-columns;
  background-color: #eee;
  }
section {
  @extend .row;
  margin-top: 20px;
  }
```

Comment: What's in `framework_and_overrides.css.scss`?

Comment: Hi @JiříPospíšil, Thanks for your message. I edited the post, see the     framework_and_overrides.css.scss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by updating the sass-rails in the gemfile.lock and then run a    bundle update    . 
After that, the error was gone!